# Creating a UV map through the Node Editor

Tags: uv, node-editor, texture-coordinates

Is there a way to create a UV map in Blender inside the node editor?

I want to create a universal UV map in a custom shader node I am building for all of the objects that use it.

I'll be using this to determine the scale of my wear and tear textures for this object. I want them to be on a universal scale (this texture is a plastic shader that is being used on some Lego packages I've made, a minifigure in this case) so that they are on a real-world scale to add to the realism of my shader.

This issue was pointed out to me by someone on Twitter (https://twitter.com/lucianomunoz_/status/1107095374299365377).

So far, I've been able to get 2/3 of my wear textures working properly (the dust and smears), but I can't seem to get the scratches working. I still can't seem to shake the feeling that I'm doing this all wrong.

[image: Problem/progress snapshot]

Comment: Not UV approach, but maybe with help of python you can calculate Bounding Box size for every object and bake corresponding value to vertex colors, then retrieve it inside shader as scale factor

Comment: I was beginning to think Python/scripting would be the only way to achieve this for now (everything nodes in Blender 2.8 may achieve this?). Unfortunately I have absolutely no experience in Python, only in C# and Java. Any tips?

Comment: I can only suggest Animation Nodes. There are both bounding box and ability to bake vertex colors